# Get current brick ID in twig template?

Tags: html, twig, pimcore, twig-extension

Currently I am creating custom bricks - sample:

```
{% set store = [] %}    
{% for i in 1..20 %}
   {% set store = store|merge([(i*8) ~ "px"]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% set heightSel = pimcore_select('heightSel', {
    store: store,
    reload: true,
    width: 100
}) %}

{% if editmode %}
    <div class="container editprop-container no-material">
        <div class="ed-col ed-col-100">
            <label>{{ "Height"|trans }}</label><br/>
            {{ heightSel|raw }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}

<div class="spacer spacer-{{ heightSel.getData()|default("0px") }}"></div>
```

Because I want to put the editing options (`.editprop-container`) into a custom modal I need some unique ID for this brick (such that it does not conflict with other bricks). Is there some possiblity to the the brick ID?

Note: A twig extension would be valid solution, but this does not help me because I do not know how to retrieve some custom ID of an editable anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting for some time I have solved it by adding randomly generated secondary IDs to the bricks:

```
 {% set modalTempId = getRandomAlnumString(20) %}
 <span class="edit-modal-opener" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#emo_{{ modalTempId }}"><i class="fal fa-cogs"></i></span>

 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="emo_{{ modalTempId }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  ...
 </div>
```

Still a better answer would be how to get the brick ID, this is a workaround which fulfills the purpose though.

Comment: Your bricks are surrounded with a `for` loop right? Why not just go with `{% for key, brick in store %}<div id="emo_{{ key }}">{% endfor %}`

Comment: @DarkBee A brick is a Pimcore specific class, its not the elements in the array. Solution is not that easy, but thanks anyway for your help.